# Chat Room Background Code

Tags: html

So I got a code to put a chat room on my website, and I was wondering how I can put a background on it, currently it's white, And is there a spot where I can change the font to: Comic sans MS,
HTML:

```
<center>
    <form id="name_form">
        Name:
        <input type=text id="name_input"
               style="width: 165px; margin: 2px" disabled>
        <input type="submit" id="connect_button" value="Connect"
               style="width: 70px; margin: 2px" disabled>
    </form>
    <textarea id="chat_box" readonly="readonly"
              style="width: 500px; height: 500px;
                     margin: 2px; resize: none"></textarea>
    </textarea>
    <form id="message_form">
        <input type=text id="message_input"
               style="width: 220px; height: 18px; margin: 2px" disabled>
        <input type="submit" id="send_button" value="Send"
               style="width: 60px; margin: 2px" disabled>
    </form>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `background` property:

```
body {
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: That CSS just changed the background color around the chat box, I'm talking about inside of the chat box.

Comment: Did you wrap it inside any container. If yes, then just apply the `background` on that container instead.